# Manually decrypting Page Note Extension add on for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have encrypted a few notes on chrome's extension called "page notes".

[image]

How can I manually decrypt these notes if I don't want to use page notes anymore? I have them saved as a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page notes uses Crypto-JS library (https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/), you can use that directly if you want to manually decrypt your notes. Something like CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted_notes, passphrase) should work.